# Cannot SVN checkout *.EXE or *.DLL to destination USB FLASH or USB HDD

Tags: svn, cygwin, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I am experiencing an error when attempting to checkout a sandbox which contains *.EXE or *.DLL files. Here are some details:

1. This FAILS for both Cygwin SVN and TortoiseSVN with the same error.
2. The checkout SUCCEEDS if checked out to the local C:\ or on a network ("net use") drive. The directory I pick to checkout to has no effect on the success or failure.
3. The problem exists on Windows 7 Pro as well as Windows 10.
4. However, I have two computers both running Windows 7 Pro, and the checkout FAILS on one, but SUCCEEDS on the other (I am logged into both computers with the same corporate login).
5. The checkout SUCCEEDS for all other files and directories, except when it gets to the *.EXE or *.DLL files, whereupon it fails with the error.
6. I have tried multiple various different USB FLASH drives and USB Hard Drives, and when the problem manifests, it always fails.
7. There are no hits in my virus scanner log, which might indicate it is interfering with the checkout. In any case, it should also interfere if the destination is C:\
8. There are no events in my Window event log as a result of this command.

Here is the specific error for Cygwin SVN:

```
svn: E155009: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with '/cygdrive/d/BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1/test', work item 1 (file-install test/heatshrink.exe 1 0 1 1)
svn: E000018: Can't move '/cygdrive/d/BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1/.svn/tmp/svn-1AtIka' to '/cygdrive/d/BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1/test/heatshrink.exe': Invalid cross-device link
```

Here is the error with Tortoise SVN:

```
Error: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with  
Error:  'D:\BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1\test', work item 1 (file-install  
Error:  test/heatshrink.exe 1 0 1 1)  
Error: Can't move 'D:\BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1\.svn\tmp\svn-35B5CA2A' to  
Error:  'D:\BT_HEATSHRINK_000003_0.3.1\test\heatshrink.exe': The system cannot move  
Error:  the file to a different disk drive.
```

Note that the error implies I am trying to do a cross-device link, but as you can see from the "from" and "to" examples, I am not. I have no weird links of any kind on my system - just vanilla Windows. I am able to manually (command line) move files, exactly as shown in the message. So there is no problem with accessing the drives. It works for C:\ and network drives, but fails for USB drives.

The Cygwin SVN is version 1.10.0 (r1827917), and the TortoiseSVN version is  1.10.0, Build 28176 - 64 Bit , 2018/04/14 08:00:32

I have scoured the web looking for a solution, and any reference to this problem I have found were truly about cross-device links. That is not the case here.

I would greatly appreciate any comments or help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Usually the cause is the virus scanner. If you can, try disabling it. There will be no `hit` logs, but the scanner may simply have the file open (for scanning) while SVN tries to move it  - this does not work on windows OS.

Comment: Re: virus scanner, I disable the scanner and the behavior didn't change. Good thought though!